# What are the consequences of solving XOR 3-SAT in Logspace?

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, complexity-classes, sat, linear-algebra, logspace

**XOR Formulas**

Consider boolean formulas with connectives $\wedge$ (AND) and $\oplus$ (XOR).  Such a boolean formula is a valid instance for XOR SAT if it is a conjunction of $\oplus$-clauses.  An $\oplus$-clause contains literals that are connected with $\oplus$.

**Example Formula:**

$(v_1 \oplus \bar{v_2} \oplus v_3 \oplus v_4) \wedge (\bar{v_1} \oplus v_2) \wedge (\bar{v_2} \oplus v_3 \oplus \bar{v_4})$

**Decision Problem**

> **Name:** XOR 3-SAT
>
> **Input:** A boolean formula that is a conjunction of $\oplus$-clauses where each clause contains three literals.
>
> **Question:** Does there exist an assignment to the variables that satisfies the formulas?

**More Background**

XOR SAT can be reduced to solving a system of equations over $\mathbb{Z}_2$.  This is because every $\oplus$-clause can be thought of as an equation.  As a result, XOR SAT is solvable in polynomial time using gaussian elimination.

Further, XOR 2-SAT can be reduced to solving reachability in an undirected graph.  This is because every $\oplus$-clause with two literals defines an edge in an undirected graph.  As a result, XOR 2-SAT is solvable in logspace because reachability in an undirected graph is solvable in logspace (because SL = L).

**Question**

> (1) Is XOR 3-SAT solvable in logspace?
>
> (2) Are there any known consequences of solving XOR 3-SAT in logspace?
>
> (3) For example, would this imply that XOR $k$-SAT is solvable in
>   logspace?

Comment: A related post: https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/36704/xor-sat-to-horn-sat-reduction/36876

Comment: @user124864 I'm not entirely sure.

Comment: I just found this which I think is relevant: https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/8936/is-solving-systems-of-equations-modulo-k-in-mathsfcomod-k-mathsf-l-for-k

Comment: There is an obvious reduction of XOR-SAT to XOR-3-SAT. Both problems are $\oplus L$-complete, hence you are simply asking about the consequences of $L=\oplus L$. Oh, and of course $\oplus L\subseteq NC^2\subseteq DSPACE((\log n)^2)$

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Take a look at https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0022000008001141 "The complexity of satisfiability problems: Refining Schaefer's theorem" by Allender et al. which answer your questions:

(1) Open

(2) $\oplus L = L$

(3) Yes

Comment: Thank you so much!!  This is exactly what I wanted!!  I didn't initially realize that we could reduce XOR SAT to XOR 3-SAT using the same trick as we do for reducing CNF SAT to CNF 3-SAT.  Also, reference [28] from the paper that you linked explains why XOR SAT is $\oplus L$ complete.